# Error while submission to app store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, code-signing, entitlements

I'm getting this error via e-mail when trying to submit my app to the app store:

> Invalid Code Signing Entitlements - Your application bundle's
>   signature contains ubiquity code signing entitlements that are not
>   supported.
>
> Specifically, value "9P774KXXX.*" for key
>   "com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier" in My App Name is not
>   supported.

I know this has something to do with iOS5/XCode 4.2, but I'm not using this - I opened the project once in XCode 4.2, and then I switched back to XCode 4.1 - so I guess there must be some leftovers in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Apple had a messed-up mobileprovisoning system for a couple of days. After I reissued, redownloaded & reinstalled a distribution provisioning profile, problems stopped.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this. I was stumped when my binary was rejected! I actually needed to create a brand new distribution profile ... just re-downloading my existing one had the same problem.

Comment: Yes, correct solution, though it probably wasn't Apple's fault - recreate/reinstall the distribution profile seems to be the consensus.

Answer (score 0):

That would be because you were using the latest iOS 5 XCode. Like you say, code was probably transferred somewhere or another. Try cleaning the project file and try it on another machine if possible to see if you get the same message.

Comment: how do I clean the project file?